# If mixins in empty show default

Tags: sass

Is it possible to have a mixin that can override a current code block? I want to have it so that if the @mixin is empty the background for the box would be empty and then show in orange, but when I remove the @mixin it does not change to orange? What am I doing wrong?

```
@mixin box {
  background: red;
}

.box {
  @if box {
    @include box;
  } @else {
    background: orange;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$color: null` is just for setting a value if you didn't pass a value for your `@mixin`. after that you can check easily inside your `@mixin` using `@if` `@else`.

Sass

```
@mixin background-color($color: null) {
  @if($color) {
    background-color: $color;
  } @else {
    background-color: orange;
  }
};

h1 {
  @include background-color(red);
 }

h2 {
  @include background-color(green);
}

h3 {
   @include background-color();
}

h4{
  @include background-color(blue)
}
```

Html

```
<h1>color</h1>
<h2>color 2</h2>
```

Comment: [demo](https://codepen.io/amryasser32/pen/RwMWZLN)